# "do not ask me again" in confirmation popup

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a  windows application that has a onw windows form. when I close the form, I want to add confirm box that ask "do you want to close this form ?" how can i show "do not ask me again" in that confirm popup in c# ?

Comment: you would create another form and store that setting in your config or user settings and read from that to either show the "do not ask me again" dialog if the setting is set to true

Comment: Really? Why do you need to ask that? Do you have some data that need to be saved? Why do you want to second guess the intention of your user? (Yes, It is true, I hate programs that ask me this question)

Comment: @Steve, then you are lucky that this program will only want to ask you once!

Comment: Yes, "once" is better than "alwas". But "never" is better than "once". If there is nothing to save, that is :O

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need a `Class` in your `Solution` which i have created is `Conformation` with three `static` public properties `_askUserAgain`,`_yes` and `_no`, for remembering the user preferences.

```
public class Confirmation
{
    public static bool _askUserAgain = true;
    public static bool _yes = false;
    public static bool _no = false;
}
```

next would be your Form1's `FormClosing` Event

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  if (Confirmation._askUserAgain == true)
   {
     e.Cancel = true;
     Form2 form2 = new Form2();
     form2.Show();
   }
  else
  {
     e.Cancel = false;
  }
}
```

next inside `Fomr2` as shown :

[image: Form2]

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Confirmation._askUserAgain = false;
    }

    private void Yes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Confirmation._yes = true;
        Confirmation._no = false;
        Form1 parentForm = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;
        if (parentForm != null)
        {
            parentForm.Hide();
        }
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void No_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Confirmation._no = true;
        Confirmation._yes = false; 
        if (Confirmation._no)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 parentForm = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;
            parentForm.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a form wich has a label, checkbox and an OK-Button.

whenever this form is closed: (the OK-Button is clicked); make sure no other possible ways for closing this form exist

```
private void OK_Click(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
 DoCheck();
 DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; //this closes your form
}

private void DoCheck()
{
 if(checkBox1.Checked)
 {
  //Set your value on true
  MyValues.Confirm = true;
 }
}
```